# Touchpad sensitivity Linux mint 18.3 Dell Inspiron 5577

Tags: linux-mint, touchpad

So I recently bought a  Dell Inspiron 5577 and have booted linux mint version 18.3 on it. Everything works fine except I am having problems with the touchpad. These include:

- jumping of the cursor
- randomly deleting text.
- moving between windows

I believe the main course of this is my left palm resting on the touchpad when I write or as I get ready to write (i.e. before I start typing). Does anyone know how I can sort this?

**Useful Info**

If I run xinput

```
⎡ Virtual core pointer                      id=2    [master pointer  (3)]
⎜   ↳ Virtual core XTEST pointer                id=4    [slave  pointer  (2)]
⎜   ↳ ELAN1010:00 04F3:3012 Touchpad            id=12   [slave  pointer  (2)]
⎜   ↳ ETPS/2 Elantech Touchpad                  id=15   [slave  pointer  (2)]
⎣ Virtual core keyboard                     id=3    [master keyboard (2)]
    ↳ Virtual core XTEST keyboard               id=5    [slave  keyboard (3)]
    ↳ Power Button                              id=6    [slave  keyboard (3)]
    ↳ Video Bus                                 id=7    [slave  keyboard (3)]
    ↳ Video Bus                                 id=8    [slave  keyboard (3)]
    ↳ Power Button                              id=9    [slave  keyboard (3)]
    ↳ Sleep Button                              id=10   [slave  keyboard (3)]
    ↳ Integrated_Webcam_HD                      id=11   [slave  keyboard (3)]
    ↳ Intel HID events                          id=13   [slave  keyboard (3)]
    ↳ AT Translated Set 2 keyboard              id=14   [slave  keyboard (3)]
    ↳ Dell WMI hotkeys                          id=16   [slave  keyboard (3)]
```

the device with id=12 has "Synaptic" properties but changing them appears to have no effect.

Comment: Fill a [bugreport](https://linuxmint-troubleshooting-guide.readthedocs.io/en/latest/index.html)

Answer (score 0):

After a bit of further reading I found this article:

http://www.dell.com/support/article/uk/en/ukbsdt1/sln308258/precision-xps-ubuntu-general-touchpad-mouse-issue-fix?lang=en

which explains how to fix the problem.